# Buying a new PC without UEFI

Tags: hardware

Is it possible to buy a new PC without the secure boot or UEFI? At some point I would like to purchase a new PC and be able to run Ubuntu and possibly a Windows OS, either dual boot or via a VM. Ubuntu would be the default OS.

Thank you!

Comment: FYI: (*trap for beginners*) For dual-boot: install *Windows 7 (32bit)* first ,then *Ubuntu* (latest OR LTS, 64bit). This does **not** effect which is the 'default' OS.

Comment: @david6 It doesn't matter in which order you install Windows or Ubuntu! If you install Ubuntu first and then windows you just need to re-install grub for it to work. But it's still possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you build your own computer you wouldn't get a UEFI, because there wouldn't be a operating system on it. But that's probably not what you meant.

You could buy a new hard drive for any computer and there wouldn't be a operating system on it, and therefor no UEFI.

This is a way to go around the UEFI problem.

Comment: Does there secure boot and/or eufi reside on the HDD or on the mother board. If either are on the MB, seems to me that the new HDD will not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you buy a slightly older model (same brand, very similar spec.: CPU, RAM, graphics), it will have Windows 7 32bit (or 64bit) and **no** UEFI. *It will also be much **cheaper** ...*

---

*Act now, or be sorry.*